# Unable to open video device

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, motion

I just installed `motion` on my Raspberry Pi 3 with the Raspbian distro, the software seems to work fine. However, I can't see any image from the local camera. I checked the log of `motion` and this is the content:

[image]

this is the result that I get in `motioneye`:

[image]

I don't know how to solve the issue, someone could help me please?

Thanks.

Comment: You should indicate what exactly the "local camera" refers to.

Comment: @goldilocks `local camera` is this device: `/dev/v4l/by-id/usb-Pixart_Imaging_Inc._CIF_Single_Chip-video-index0`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A short [Google](https://google.com) search for `Device doesn't support VIDIOC_G_STD` gave these two links:

- [Raspberry Pi • View topic - Motion errors for RPi camera](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=76558&p=546467)
- [Unable to open video device · Issue #147 · ccrisan/motioneyeos](https://github.com/ccrisan/motioneyeos/issues/147)

The first page suggests:

- Check for `ls /dev/video*`, no output means your **camera is not connected properly or driver is missing**
- If a camera is recognized, **tweak some config files**
- If not, **give the older Raspbian Wheezy a try**, it was reported to work much better than the newer Jessie.

The second one (GitHub issue) concludes that the **camera is simply not compatible**, so try with another one.

Hope this helps and good luck in resolving this issue!

Comment: Hello, when I type `ls /dev/video*` I get: `/dev/video0` so this should indicate that the device is correctly connected. I don't understood the point two where you said `tweak some config files`, which config files? And I can't format the raspberry, I've too much things installed.. Thanks.

Comment: Have you even read the pages? The second post on the first one says:

*Try adding this line to the bottom of your /etc/motion.conf (I haven't tested this): `input -1`

Then restart motion with `sudo service motion restart`*

Comment: yes, I've added this line but same error message, the camera device is however this: /dev/v4l/by-id/usb-Pixart_Imaging_Inc._CIF_Single_Chip-video‌​-index0

Comment: Then read the whole thread there, or get another SD card and test with Wheezy. Jessie was reported to have issues with some software several times where it worked like a charm previously.

Comment: I just reinstalled motion, actually seems that if I go into http://192.168.1.10:8081 I can see the interface of motion (with the same problem of gray camera screen), but if I access to motioneye typing: http://192.168.1.10:8765 I get this error: ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED, why happen this?

Comment: Looks like the Pi isn't listening on that port and therefore refusing the connection

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52477/discussion-between-againme-and-linusg).

Comment: I'm back, if you want to continue chatting :)

Comment: Very good user, he has assisted me. The problem was an incompatible webcam.

Comment: Sorry for not answering, my battery was down. I can give you no advice to IP cameras since I've never used one but I guess a simple USB cam will do the  (look that it is reported to work with the Pi)

Comment: However, glad this is now clearly solved to be a Hardware issue. Feel free to ask for help if you do another attemp :)

Answer (score 6):

Try this: 
sudo modprobe bcm2835-v4l2

if works then put above line in /etc/rc.local to run this at boot time.

Comment: It worked for me, but it'd be great with some explanations.

Comment: worked for me too, but agreed with @AnthonyB .. why does it work ?

Comment: This should be comment, not answer.
@AnthonyB `modprobe bcm2835-v4l2` is installing/loding module bcm2835-v4l2 which is required to run the camera.

Comment: @amrx I know it today but I didn't know it 3 years ago. Thank you for this comment, should have been explained with the answer.

Comment: cant seem to access the rc.local folder

Answer (score 0):

If you are using USB camera, then uninstall the RPI web interface and then install fswebcam and ffmpeg and then start the motion.

Hope it does work!

Thanks,
Kavi